# how to determine line number for the fields with different number of data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which is contains:

> id, sender, recepients
>
> `1   1     2`
>
> `2   1     2,3,4,5`

In the display page, I have to show recepient with more than 1 item separately as an independent row with independent line number. With my old script, display that appears is, field 1 with the number 1. And field 2 (multiple item) also begins with 1. It should continue the number of field 1.

Current display of it:

> `no.    id    sender    recepients`
>
> `1.     1       1           2`
>
> `1.     2       1           2  // the No. should be 2`
>
> `2.     2       1           3`
>
> `3.     2       1           4`
>
> `4.     2       1           5`

Its display should:

> `no.    id    sender    recepients`
>
> `1.     1       1           2`
>
> `2.     2       1           2`
>
> `3.     2       1           3`
>
> `4.     2       1           4`
>
> `5.     2       1           5`

**Current code:**

```
$i=0;

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {

        $i++;

$tuj = explode(",",$r['recepients']);

for ($c=$i; $c < count($tuj)+$i; $c++) {

    //display data
}
```

**Question:**

What should I do to determine number of line? Whether it's done in SQL or PHP?

Comment: Please clarify two things: 1) what is your "old script" (can you show the code?) and 2) is the second table you show the output that you want to get? Or the output you are currently getting? Do you want to include the numbers?

Comment: Please show your code the creates the `no.` value. It looks like you might be reseting the number on each row, instead of increasing it.

Comment: it's not a second table. I've change the description. I'm sorry.. :)

Comment: Your using a counter variable, right? Please post your code.

Comment: @LoganWayne: yes, I use a counter variable. but, I'm totally newbie.. :)

Comment: @Peter: I've had edited the description.. :)

Comment: Seems fine with me, based on your summarized code. Maybe there's something happening inside your for loop that changes or revert the variable $i. Check thoroughly your variable $i inside the for loop

Comment: You still have not shown where you set your `no.` column value. You just gave us `//display data`

Comment: Since no one's pointed this out, also note that **MYSQL_** functions are deprecated, and should not be used on new code. Check out PDO/MySQLi, they're safer and IMO easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use brute force assuming the number of recipients is not too long:

```
select t.id, t.sender,
       substring_index(substring_index(recipients, ',', n.n), ',', -1) as recipient
from table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
where n.n <= (1 + length(recipients) - length(replace(recipients, ',', ''));
```

The `where` clause counts the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want to do - I replaced the database lookup with a hard coded array for testing, but you should be able to replace my `foreach` with your `while` and have working code:

```
<?php
    $lineCount=1;

    echo "no.   id   sender  recepients\n";
    $a[0]=array('id'=>12, 'sender'=>123, 'recepients'=>"1");
    $a[1]=array('id'=>13, 'sender'=>124, 'recepients'=>"1,2,3");
    $a[2]=array('id'=>14, 'sender'=>125, 'recepients'=>"2,3,4,5,6");
    foreach ($a as $r) {
    //while($r = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {
      $tuj = explode(",",$r['recepients']);
      for ($c=0; $c < count($tuj); $c++) {
        echo $lineCount++."     ".$r['id']."    ".$r['sender']."      ".$tuj[$c]."\n";
      }
    }
?>
```

Output of the above:

```
no.   id   sender  recepients
1     12    123      1
2     13    124      1
3     13    124      2
4     13    124      3
5     14    125      2
6     14    125      3
7     14    125      4
8     14    125      5
9     14    125      6
```

Notes:

I used a variable called `lineCount` to count lines

I used variable `$c` to count elements in the `$tuj` array. You were offsetting `$c` by `$i` which was somehow confounding the use of `$c` as either a line counter or a index counter.

Clear naming of variables can help if you want to write code that's easy to debug...